# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Blender breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  2         14
Users destroyed                                  26          0
Users deleted                                    11          0
Users contacted                                   6          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           326      2,324
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue              103        220
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        719      2,998
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              272      1,096
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               792      7,222
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue            1,021      6,171
Tag highlight language set                        1          0
Revisions redacted                                5          0
Questions reopened                               35         11
Questions protected                              26         39
Questions migrated                                3          4
Questions flagged⁴                               10        702
Questions closed                                950      1,390
Question flags handled⁴                         210        502
Posts unlocked                                    0          1
Posts undeleted                                  98        148
Posts locked                                      0         41
Posts deleted⁵                                1,239      4,495
Posts bumped                                      0      8,716
Comments undeleted                                4          0
Comments flagged                                  0      1,766
Comments deleted⁶                               745      4,375
Comment flags handled                           329      1,437
Bounties canceled                                 1          0
Answers flagged                                  19      2,929
Answer flags handled                          2,421        527
All comments on a post moved to chat              3          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Nice wrap up post. Is this a new thing you will be doing, or have I just forgotten, or missed it?

Comment: I've done it ad-hoc in the past, but never before had the temerity to hit 160 sites at once

Comment: I counted 156, some sites were skipped: Monero, iota, Augur...

Comment: Should've been 162, but I may have missed something, @user12855. Those three were just last in the queue.

Comment: [Spanish Language](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions) did not get one, for example. Also, you skipped localized SO but posted on the localized [Русский язык](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/373/2018-a-year-in-moderation).

Comment: Good eye, @user12855. Removed that one, will do another pass tomorrow & see what else got missed.

Comment: For the curious, [What is the difference between a deleted user and a “destroyed” user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user).

Comment: Ok, Spanish is up @user12855. The other two missing ones were Emacs and SFF; I had a bit too liberal a check in place to prevent duplicate posting, so tightening that up allowed the rest to go through.

Comment: Shog9 and @user12855 I'll add that there is also some discussion in chat about metas where such post is missing: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1292/2019/1/1 https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1292/2019/1/2